# After i have updated my android studio its showing error like Android resource compilation failed.please help me

Tags: android, android-studio

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Users\DevoDev1\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1339: error: unescaped apostrophe in string
"Who should feed "First Feed" or Anna Prasana to the baby? \n\n (a) Father \n (b) Mother \n (c) Uncle (Mother's Brother) \n (d) Grand Father (Month's father) \n\n Who else can feed first?".
C:\Users\DevoDev1\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1339: error: not a valid string.
C:\Users\DevoDev1\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1343: error: unescaped apostrophe in string
"Lamp should be facing our side or God\'s side \n\n (a) To God side, because we are offering to God \n (b) Our side, because we need the God's grace on us \n (c) Doesn't matter \n\n What is your take?".
C:\Users\DevoDev1\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1343: error: not a valid string.
C:\Users\DevoDev1\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1455: error: unescaped apostrophe in string
"Don't loosen your belt".
C:\Users\DevoDev1\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1455: error: not a valid string.
```

Command: C:\Users\DevoDev1.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\85067246fdfeb2b4bb965a42850c6b89\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\DevoDev1\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Users\DevoDev1\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
[image]

Comment: restart your android studio then clean and rebuild

Comment: I have restarted the studio but showing the same error.

Comment: have you clean and rebuild the project

Comment: yes, I have cleaned and rebuild.

Comment: then delete cache build files

Comment: I have another copy file of my project. At present I am using that old one's, but some changes that i have made in the old project have lost .I don't know what i have did, i just updated the studio nothing i have changed. Anyway thanks for the immediate response.

Comment: can you show your values.xml

Comment: I deleted the project but I have attached the image to my question itself you can see there.

Answer (score 4):

The errors are in your strings file. Replace this strings

```
Who should feed "First Feed" or Anna Prasana to the baby? \n\n (a) Father \n (b) Mother \n (c) Uncle (Mother's Brother) \n (d) Grand Father (Month's father) \n\n Who else can feed first?

Lamp should be facing our side or God\'s side \n\n (a) To God side, because we are offering to God \n (b) Our side, because we need the God's grace on us \n (c) Doesn't matter \n\n What is your take?

Don't loosen your belt
```

With:

```
Who should feed \"First Feed\" or Anna Prasana to the baby? \n\n (a) Father \n (b) Mother \n (c) Uncle (Mother\'s Brother) \n (d) Grand Father (Month\'s father) \n\n Who else can feed first?

Lamp should be facing our side or God\'s side \n\n (a) To God side, because we are offering to God \n (b) Our side, because we need the God\'s grace on us \n (c) Doesn\'t matter \n\n What is your take?

Don\'t loosen your belt
```

You missed some apostrophe and some double quotes

Comment: I have replaced it with my old string. but showing only one error in the values.xml file that - cannot find the declaration of the element resources

Comment: Are your strings contained into <resources></resources>?

Comment: I see that you posted the screenshot of your error. Did you correct the strings? In the screenshot you still have the wrongs one

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Try to open values.xml via Project in android studio

```
C:\Users\DevoDev1\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
```

find lines: 1339, 1343, 1455 and edit them.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem after updating to 3.3.2. I ignored the current project and fresh clone or create a new project which solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had several apostrophes in the strings that were tagged with errors.  Unfortunately, the Android Studio IDE does not red-underline all words with apostrophes if there are several apostrophes in a string, so it is very easy to miss apostrophes.  Look carefully at the error report and double check the strings that are labeled.  You may find that you escaped SOME of the apostrophes in the string, but not all of them